# JAVA selenium grid: register remote machine as node is giving failed connection refused error in Grid console

Tags: java, selenium

Grid console http://localhost:4444/grid/console

error message:

> DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to 10.152.140.119:5558
>   [/10.152.140.119] failed: Connection refused: connect

Requirement to register MachineA as hub and MachineB as node on the hub. So as to run selenium scripts simultaneously on both the machines on different browsers

Steps to reproduce:

- Step1: execute below on hub machine's cmd prompt to register the hub

  ```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role hub
  ```
- Step2: execute below on hub machine's cmd prompt to register the remote machine as node

  ```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http:/10.152.140.170:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -host  10.152.140.119 -browser browserName=firefox
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to 10.152.140.119:5558 [/10.152.140.119] failed: Connection refused: connect

the above message no longer exists once the remote sharing in enabled between the hub and the node desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed a few things. If I understand you correclt, you try to set up the node from hub - this is not right. You should do the opposite. Here you can find detailed setup guide:

http://automatictester.co.uk/2012/08/26/selenium-grid-tutorial-from-webdriver-to-grid-2-0/

Comment: Thank you, 
"if we have nodes on different location, should we go on each node to register it on the hub and then execute scripts". 
Or  from the hub machine alone we can both register remote nodes and run scripts. Any inputs on this would be of great help to us.
NOTE: 
executing the below cmd on hub machines  helped in registering the node on hub but when executing test scripts browser failed to launch on the machines.

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http:/10.152.140.170:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -host  10.152.140.119 -browser browserName=firefox

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and found out the IP configuration of few nodes is not correct.

Even though Node was able to connect to the hub, Hub was not able to send any request to launch browsers to start test in those nodes

Resolved after changing the ipconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your browser to thre atest version - including your geckodriver and stand-alone server. If that doesn't help then it could be your firewall blocking the ports. To check this open up CMD and type the following comand: nestat - n. See if the port you're using appears on the list - if not then - Try to enable the port. Restart everything and try to run your test again